# Как создать неопределенное количество переменных в Python

Tags: python, переменные

В кратце, есть база данных, в ней лежат данные для входа в телеграм аккаунты, программа должна посчитать сколько аккаунтов есть в базе и создать такое количество переменных чтобы с ними далее работать, грубо говоря в базе 3 аккаунта, будет создано
`client1 = TelegramClient() client2 = TelegramClient() client3 = TelegramClient()`
Реализуемо ли это в Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В базовом Python для работы в таких условиях существует объект типа список.

```
clients=[]
for _ in range (n):
    clients.append(TelegramClient())
```

О том, где об этом можно прочитать -  писать не буду, потому-как ответ: в ЛЮБОЙ книжке по Python. И еще один неожиданный совет: учить Python и читать соответствующие книги  рекомендуется до того, как начинать писать телеботы.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 10 # Number of accounts
for i in range(n):
    exec(f'client{i} = TelegramClient()')
```